# How to change the child character model in unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character creator script that creates a player gameobject with the character model as a child

```
public class CreatePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
   [MenuItem("GameObject/Create Player", false, 10)]
    
    static void Create()
    {
        GameObject player = new GameObject("Hero");
        player.tag = "Player";
        GameObject character = Instantiate((GameObject)Resources.Load("SampleCharacter")); // Instantiate the 3D model
        character.transform.parent = player.transform;
        CharacterController cc = player.AddComponent<CharacterController>();
        cc.center = new Vector3(0f, 0.9f, 0f);
        cc.radius = 0.2f;
        cc.height = 1.9f;
        player.AddComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        Animator animator = character.AddComponent<Animator>();
        animator.runtimeAnimatorController = (RuntimeAnimatorController)Resources.Load("Animations/PlayerAnimation");
        player.AddComponent<PlayerAnimations>();
        player.AddComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        Camera.main.gameObject.AddComponent<CameraController>();
        Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraController>().followTarget = player.transform;
    }
    
}
```

What I need is to be able to change the character model whenever needed after the character creation in the editor by dragging and dropping a character prefab. This should also apply the animator and animation controller as well to the new prefab added.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options.

1. Destroy the character entirely (with the Destroy(GameObject) function) and load in a new one as a child whenever you switch.
2. Call GetComponentInChildren< T>() to get the MeshRenderer and Animator components and swap out the necessary properties (*sharedMesh* and *controller* respectively) manually.  That one may be a bit trickier and have some bugs to work out.  You'll probably also need to destroy and load in the entire skeleton if you're using skinned meshes, and hook up the necessary references on the new one.